# Does Apache Tika keep parsed data?

Tags: python, api, ocr, apache-tika

I'm using tika-python to extract text from files, it works well. But because the files need to be parsed contain some confidential information, so I'm wondering as Apache Tika is an API, does it keep the parsed data? Or the data would be released after the parsing process ends?

Comment: Are you running the Apache Tika server on your own machine? Or are you communicating with a hosted copy elsewhere?

Comment: I'm using this package, https://github.com/chrismattmann/tika-python, but I don't understand how things work...

Comment: By default, that grab the Tika Server jar and runs it locally